# How to properly rotate a virtual sphere?

Tags: three.js

I create points based on the fibonacci sphere, then using TextGeometry I create a virtual sphere from the resulting positions.
How i can rotate this virtual sphere with no effect on text nodes?

```js
function fibonacciSphere(numPoints, point) {
  const rnd = 1;
  const offset = 2 / numPoints;
  const increment = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));

  const y = point * offset - 1 + offset / 2;
  const r = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(y, 2));

  const phi = ((point + rnd) % numPoints) * increment;

  const x = Math.cos(phi) * r;
  const z = Math.sin(phi) * r;

  return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
}

const loader = new FontLoader();

const group = new THREE.Group();

function main() {
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 100);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  function addTextNode(text, vert) {
    loader.load("./fonts/Fira.json", function (font) {
      const geometry = new TextGeometry(text, {
        font: font,
        size: 0.16,
        height: 0.01,
      });
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.x = vert.x;
      mesh.position.y = vert.y;
      mesh.position.z = vert.z;

      group.add(mesh);
      scene.add(group);
    });
  }

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  const container = document.querySelector("#root");
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const numPoints = 50;
  for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
    addTextNode(`p${i}`, fibonacciSphere(numPoints, i));
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    // group.rotation.x += 0.01;

    scene.traverse((child) => {
      child.children.map((el) => {
        el.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
      });
    });

    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

I direct them to face the camera, but when I try to rotate this group of elements, it stands still if I don't remove the rotation to the camera.